# Передать параметр из дочерних компонентов в родительский - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Требуется решить следующую задачу с использованием React:**

1. Есть компонент `<Field onUpdateValues={this.updateValues}>`
2. Есть компонент `<Tree>`.
3. Компонент `<Tree>` всегда содержит `<Field>`. Из компонентов `<Tree>` рекурсивно строится дерево.
4. И есть главный `<div>` - контейнер , с которого начинается отрисовка `<Tree>`.

**Вопрос:** как передать значение параметра из каждого Field до главного контейнера? Field, Tree - их может быть куча, т.к. дерево.

**Из Field в Tree значение у меня получается передавать, типа так:**

В родительском Tree:

```js
    updateValues(id) {
            console.log('TADA' + id);
        }

<Field onUpdateValues={this.updateValues}></Field >
```

В дочернем Field:

```js
    this.props.onUpdateValues(this.state.id);
```

В кратце, узлы дерева все выводятся за раз, каждый узел дерева содержит Checkbox (находится в Field). И вот в родительском элементе мне надо получить json-список вида со всей информацией о Checkbox'ах в узлах:

```js
{
    answer:[
        {
          id:1,
          checked:0
        },
        {
           id:2,
           checked:1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Пример передачи родителю от ребёнка через транзитный узел:

```
class Field extends React.Component {
    updated = () => {
        this.props.updated(100);
    }

    render() {
        return <input type="checkbox" value={100} onClick={this.updated}/>;
    }
}

class Tree extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Field updated={this.props.updated} />;
    }
}

class Div extends React.Component {
    updated = (id) => {
        alert(id);
    }

    render() {
        return <Tree updated={this.updated}/>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Div/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

2. Состояние хранить в Div.
3. Примеры:

а) Пример с Div, Tree, Field: https://jsfiddle.net/zsqwL40b/

б) + сохранение в JSON: https://jsfiddle.net/j6scy02b/3/

Comment: Большое спасибо! То что нужно 1 в 1, решил проблему.

Comment: @Alex Отлично! Рад, что удалось помочь.